# How to set default marker position in google map api

Tags: api, google-maps, google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-api

I am using google map API I want to set default lat and long in marker. I have a location I want to open that location by default when map is loaded then it should be opened as the set location. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Write this in your mapReady function

```
    @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // enter the latitude and longitude in place of -35,151 respectively
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```